# Rails 3 & Paperclip - Can I store images both on S3 & locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave

We have a situation where we would like to start hosting images on Amazon's S3 service, however we don't want to upload all of our existing images to S3, instead we want to serve these "legacy" images from where they are hosted at the moment & going forward upload all new images to S3 and obviously serve those from S3.

Does anyone know if this is possible using either PaperClip or CarrierWave?

Thanks!

Comment: Simple solution why not create  2 different column assign them 2 different storage  one file and other s3  (and assign them same file during updating or creating a new record)

Answer (score 0):

Here how you do this if you don't have a any version create a version called `:s3_version`(anything you like)

something like this

```
class YourUploader < CarrierWave::Base

storage :file

version :s3_version do 
  storage :fog
  ## As far as I know it would save the file with appending 's3_version_(your_file_name)
  
  def full_filename(for_file)
    super.gsub(/s3_version_/,"")
  end

  def filename
    self.to_s.gsub(/s3_version_/,'')
  end
end
```

I think this would do all you want storing the `file` both locally as well as on `S3` .

### WARNING :

```
    I haven't tested this with multiple version
```

but I guess it can too be done with `:from` clause I believe

Something like this

```
   version :thumb do
        process resize_to_fill: [280, 280] 
     end
 
     version :s3_thumb, :from_version => :thumb do
        storage :s3
      end
```

haven't tested it though

Hope this help